# Factorization of $a^p-b^p \; ; p\in \text{prime}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a method for figuring out a factorization of $a^p - b ^p$ where $p$ is prime?  This may be stupid, but I couldn't find the answer with Google.

Comment: $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\dots+a^{2}b^{n-3}+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$ is one step you can take regardless of whether $n$ is prime or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use
$$a^p - b^p = (a - b)(a^{p-1} + a^{p-2}b + a^{p-3}b^2 + \ldots + a^2 b^{p-3} + ab^{p - 2} + b^{p-1}).$$

Comment: I recognize that.  I mean is there some way to factor the other part further when the exponent is prime.